# How to set a step for dynamic size of an eöement in CSS?

Tags: html, css, block, dynamic-sizing

I have a form, that has optically two sides (left and right). The height of the input fields is constant, so the left and the right fields are placed exactly on the same "lines".

[image]

Now I want to add description/comment blocks under some of the fields. The "lines" may not be broken. It's no problem for short comment, that need only one "line". I can simply set the `min-height` to the height of the input fields. But longer texts will need multiple line breaks and so destroy my imaginary "lines".

So what I need, is a way to define something like a "step" for the comment blocks. so that if a comment block contains multiple lines of text, it grows by one or more `heights` (e.g.: the `height` is `20px`; then the block can become greater to contain more text, but only in `20px` steps like `40`, `60` `80`, etc.).

How to do this with pure CSS (without JavaScript)?

Comment: do you have a plunker?

Comment: In typography, it's called *vertical rythm*. Harder to achieve when label and form elements are involved than with _just_ hN, p and lists :) And +1 for an actual pen/fiddle/real code thing where it isn't achieved yet